# Phonegap malformed config.xml file and Google Play Console error with new version of app

Tags: android, phonegap, google-play-console

I have a made a small change my phonegap app (no new plugins), and I want to do a phonegap build, sign it and upload it to the GP Console.

I changed the top line of the config.xml file from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1:

```
<widget id="net.kiwiroad.quiz" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

but now phonegap build tells me the config file is malformed.

If I try to upload it without making the version change, GP Console says: "Upload failed. You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 10000"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run the `prepare` command. It updates the version on all the platforms and formats your XML correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains it: "You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 10000".

[Versioning is explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning). It says:

> versionCode — A positive integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName setting, below. The Android system uses the versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version currently installed on their device.

You can either define this in your manifest or in gradle for a normal Android APK.

I've never used phonegap, but [from the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/) it looks like this is set in the config.xml

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >
```

Try adding a versionCode attribute with a value greater than 10000. Maybe 10001?